# How use style css in yii2-swiftmailer?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How use style css in yii2-swiftmailer?

I not know how use css style in yii2-swiftmailer. Css style  not add from css class `.button3`.

I try:

/controllers/SiteController

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('messager', ['testparams' => 'trtrtrtrt',])
 ->setFrom('ergegergerger@gmail.com')
 ->setTo('ergergergegerg@mail.ru')
 ->setSubject('TEST')
 ->send();
```

/mail/messager.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>

<?= Html::encode($testparams) ?>
```

/mail/layouts/html.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;



/* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
/* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
/* @var $content string main view render result */
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />

    <style type="text/css">
       .button3{
        background-color: green;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <?php $this->head() ?>

</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>


    <?= $content ?>

    <div class="button3">Приветик test !</div>


    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Comment: Try inline styling and check if its working..

Comment: @ck_arjun inline styling good worked - `<div style="background-color: green;">Приветик !</div>`

Comment: @ck_arjun Me need Css style  add from css class .button3

Comment: Do you set htmlLayout?

Comment: @SiZE Yes, htmlLayout or View (messager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the CSS common to all emails in `/mail/layouts/html.php` at the top.

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {padding: 0, margin: 0;}
</style>
```

Similarly, add CSS specific to the email in the email itself, e.g. `/mail/messager.php`

```
<style type="text/css">
  .className {padding: 0, margin: 0;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS this way in your file /mail/layouts/html.php

```
$this->registerCss("
   .button3{background-color: green;width: 100px;height: 100px;
        }
");
```